# Can you add a Azure Webjob to a Blazor Server solution?

Tags: blazor, azure-webjobs

I am currently looking to change an Azure Web Application from .Net Framework 4.8 to Blazor Server .Net 6.

The .net framework solution has one web app and numerous web jobs (continuous and triggered).

Can you add Azure web jobs to a Blazor Server application or do you need to create a separate asp.net core project to host them?

Regards,
Graham

Comment: If you mean under web jobs individual (console) apps thar run in the background, then you can utilize the same Azure App Service to host multiple web jobs and your Blazor server.

Comment: That is what I mean but.

From within Visual Studio 2022 if I try and add a web job to the existing blazor project: 

Right click Blazor Project:
-Add
-New Azure Web Job Project

A dialog box displays an error message stating: 

'The command is not applicable for the selected project.'

Comment: @GrahamO'Riley I think it's a tooling issue. You get the same error message when you add webjob to your basic web project as well. Best bet is to submit feedback through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***Add -> New/Existing Web Job*** are legacy functionalities that are only applicable to ASP.NET full framework projects. You can still add your web job as a project to the solution. For .NET Framework, there's still an available *Azure WebJob (.NET Framework)* project template. For .NET Core, just create a console app and publish it as a web job.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. This lead me to the microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs Personally I think they should have created a template in VS2022 but at least I know how to do it. So thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I'll add a note to the docs better clarifying the differences in VS2022.